# How would i get this weird dark effect that is achieved on the netflix app

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[Im talking about this dark effect that is circled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9XVD.png)

I'm trying to make a Netflix clone but i just can't figure out how to get this weird effect while scrolling. It looks like they just added this dark thing and when the page is scrolled up and down it looks really nice. I personally don't think they used animation or something of that sort but I could be wrong.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/blurred-borders-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that is a box shadow. Apply this CSS element to the black div underneath the thumbnail:

```css
box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 10px black
```

The syntax is this:

```css
box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius] [optional spread radius] [color];
```